# Read 100 Numbers from a text file and find minimum and maximum values

Tags: c++

> Created a text file and put in 100 random numbers. Trying to read the file.
> The text file looks like:
>
> ```
> 27 12 37 53 83 2
> ```

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int i,min,max;
       ifstream fin;
       fin.open("DATA.txt",ios::in);
       fin>>i;
       max=i;
       min=i;

       while(fin>>i)
       {
           if(i>max)
               max=i;
           if(i<min)
               min=i;
       }
       cout<<max<<" "<<min;
       fin.close();
   }
```

> I originally tried to do it using read function but it gives garbage values. Why does this code not work?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int i,min,max;
       ifstream fin;
       fin.open("DATA.txt",ios::in);
       fin.read((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
       max=i;
       min=i;
       while(fin)
       {
           fin.read((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
           if(i>max)
               max=i;
           if(i<min)
               min=i;
       }
       cout<<max<<" "<<min;
       fin.close();
   }
```

Comment: `read()` is intended to read chunks of bytes (usually to read binary files). You stated that your file is a text file i.e. contains the integral numbers encoded as characters (with decimal digits). The formatted input `fIn >> i` is the absolute correct method to read this (which includes conversion of these "textual" number representations into binary encoded integrals).

Comment: The `read()` might have been the correct if the numbers had been written into a binary file e.g. by `fOut.write((const char*)&i, sizeof i);` (and assuming `int i;`, of course) though there would be still the potential issue with endianess mentioned by @Jarod42. Aside from the endianess, there's actually the other possible issue that an `int` hasn't a guaranteed size by the standard (but only a guaranteed minimum size). Though,  nowadays it's probably hard to find a platform with something else than 32 bit `int`s. However, the standard provides e.g. `std::int32_t` for the rescue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int i,min,max;
       ifstream fin;
       fin.open("DATA.txt",ios::in);
       max=INT_MIN; // least possible int value
       min=INT_MAX; // largest possible int value

       while(fin>>i)// reads till the end of file
       {
           if(i>max)
               max=i;
           if(i<min)
               min=i;
       }
       cout<<max<<" "<<min;
       fin.close();
   }
```

Comment: Although this is a good tip on how to improve the code, your "answer" makes no attempt at answering the actual question. Therefore, it is not a proper answer. If you want your post to be upvoted, you may want to rectify this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` (which is true on most platforms), the first time you execute the line

`fin.read((char*)&i,sizeof(i));`

it will read the first 4 bytes (=characters) of the file, which are `"27 1"`. Assuming the file is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded, these 4 bytes have the following values:

1. `50` ([ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/) for the digit `'2'`)
2. `55` (ASCII code for the digit `'7'`)
3. `32` (ASCII code for the character `' '`)
4. `49` (ASCII code for the digit `'1'`)

Assuming that you are on a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) platform, the mentioned byte values will result in an `int` with the value `824,194,866`.

This is what happens when you read your text file as binary data, which is obviously not what you want. What you want is to read the file as text. You want to read digits until you encounter a non-digit character, interpret these digits as a number, and then write that number to an `int` variable. This is exactly what the `<<` stream extraction operator does in the expression `fin>>i` that you are using.

Therefore, your second piece of code is fundamentally incorrect, because it interprets the file data as binary, whereas your first piece of code is fundamentally correct, as it interprets the file data as text.

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered. However, we should not go without an additional solution that shows the "more modern" C++ approach.

And therefore I offer the below answer for your kind evaluation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened. (using C++17 features)
    if (std::ifstream dataFileStream{ "data.txt" }; dataFileStream) {

        // Read all values and get iterator to min and max element
        const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(std::istream_iterator<int>(dataFileStream), {});
        
        // Show result to user
        std::cout << "Min: " << *min << " \t Max: " << *max << '\n';
    }
    else {
        // File could not be opened. Show error
        std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open source file\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a short and compact solution. Without any loop.

Maybe somebody will be inspired by it.

Comment: While yes, this is a more modern approach, be wary of dumping too much information on a user trying to figure out the difference between `iostream` and `read`. You need to gauge the level of your answer to the question. Loading up new concepts like `std::pair` masked by `auto` and the finer points of the [Algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) will likely just result in their eyes glazing over and rolling back in their head. (though it is a nice answer for an algorithms question -- and for that reason worthy of an upvote -- tenuously)